# Arrays were different lengths: ... (numpy meshgrid linspace) Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am having the following errors:

`ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 147 vs 150`

`ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 148 vs 150`

etc.

while running the following Python code:

```
    x = np.linspace(1, 15, 15, endpoint=True)
    y = np.linspace(1, 10, 10, endpoint=True)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = data[data["var2"] == X & data["var3"] == Y]["search_column"]
```

I am pretty sure the problem appears due to non-existing matches of `"var1"` and `"var2"` with `X` and `Y`, but I am not sure how to fix this error. I wish the missing values to be `None`, if possible. In that case, I think probably creating something like Z with `None`s first would fix my problem.

Note that I don't really want to create those `None` values in my initial `data`. However, if there is no other options let me know.

I would appreciate any advice from you!

Thank you!

Edit: `data` is pd.DataFrame

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you're trying to do with the last line of code.

Comment: @FrankYellin I am trying to create Z data for plotting 3D graph from this data. X, Y, Z are represented by different columns in ```data``` (pd.DataFrame), but not all entries exist. Basically the last line finds the corresponding row(not rowsas there is either none or 1 combination of X and Y in ```data```). And then column ```["search_column"]``` together with the row gives the value of Z. Sorry I deleted ```["search_column"]``` when posted question and now added.

Comment: (data["var2"] == X) & (data["var3"] == Y)

Comment: Tell us about `data`

Comment: Change manually the values inside your ´data´ variable, everything that is NaN or empty change to 0 or some number that clearly show you that this data was not completed.